# Can I use HTTPS and SSE client libraries on Arduino PORTENTA Machine Control board?

Tags: firebase, https, arduino, iot, micropython

*I am looking for simple board for IoT professional projects. I bumped into the [Arduino PORTENTA Machine Control board](https://www.arduino.cc/pro/hardware/product/portenta-machine-control) a while back, but I cannot get some things sorted out:*

- **What libraries can I use on this board (mainly `SSE` and `HTTPS` libraries)?**
- Does it have enough computational power to do `HTTPS` requests (not `HTTP` but `HTTPS`)?

**What am I trying to achieve:**

- I am trying to build a project around Google’s Firestore / Firebase.
- I need to communicate to it via `REST API`.
- Google enables only `HTTPS` communication with their databases – and
  normal Arduino boards can’t do `HTTPS` requests because they do not
  have enough power.
- So, I need either `SSE client` + `HTTPS requests` library to run on the
  PORTENTA board **OR** Firebase Realtimedatabase library (I know the
  library is built on `HTTPS requests` – but if it’s not compatible I can
  recreate it with `SSE client` and `HTTPS requests`).

---

**Other info:**

- By `SSE` I mean `Server Send Events` for Realtime communication and
  updates to the board :)
- I have no problem programming it in native Arduino language or in Micropython.
- The answer below states that I can use those libraries if the board is supported - but I don't know how to know if the board is supported :/

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard that Arduino lacks the power for HTTPS requests and Arduino have documentation on how to make HTTPS requests for many of their official boards: https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-https-request

If you are using an unsupported board you will have to route the traffic to another host first. Either another Arduino or an ESP to act as the main host/client that it can communicate to access external resources such as Firebase.

Comment: I meant basic boards such as UNO, MEGA, DUE etc. I know some more advanced boards can do it - I just want to know if the portenta boards can make HTTPS requests. Since they are ready for use in production (not like MKR - at least to my knowledge). But thanks for pointing this out! Do you happen to know if Portenta boards can do HTTPS?

Comment: FYI here is Q about why Arduino boards can't do HTTPS (this was the source of my information): https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/11/71751